# How to automatize listing many elements within a command line in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind

I have a set of 23 dataframes, all called sequentially like this: data_1, data_2,...,data_23.
I want to rbind them together without typing all the dataframe names out in the command line.
So, instead of `rbind(data_1,data_2,...,data_23)` I am searching for a convenient way to get this done quickly.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^data_\\d+$")))`

Comment: fantastic, works thank you!